# How Find all linear polynomials orthogonal to $f(t) = t$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonal-polynomials

$(f,g) =  \sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac{k}{n})g(\frac{k}{n})$, where $f,g \in P_n$, the linear space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$.

If $f(t) = t$, find all linear polynomials $g$ orthogonal to $f$.

I tried doing $\sum_{t=0}^n \frac{t}{n}\frac{at+b}{n} = 0$. That gave me $\frac{a(2n+1)}{3n} - b = 0$.

This isn't right. I know the answer is $g(t) = a(t-\frac{2n+1}{3n})$, where $a$ is arbitrary.

Comment: The space of such polynomials will be a subspace, and you have found the correct answer, which is that the set of affine polynomials that are orthogonal to $f$ is given by $t \mapsto at+b$, where $a,b$ satisfy the condition above. Since $b$ satisfies the equality above, you can substitute for $b$ and get the $g$ above.

Comment: "Since b satisfies the equality above, you can substitute for b and get the g above." -which equality are you referring to? What am I substituting for b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have a good start!

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{n}\frac{ak+b}{n} = {\frac { \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 2\,n+1 \right) a}{6n}}+{
\frac { \left( n+1 \right) b}{2n}}=0.
 $$

Solve the above equation for $a$ and $b$ (you have one free variable) which gives

$$ a=s,\quad b = -\frac{(2n+1)s}{3}, \quad s\in \mathbb{R}. $$

Now substitute back for the values of $a,b$ in $g(t)$ to get

$$ g(t) = st + \frac{(2n+1)s}{3} = s\left( t - \frac{(2n+1)}{3} \right) = a\left( t - \frac{(2n+1)s}{3} \right) $$

since $s$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: So I don't see how this gives the solution g(t) = a(t - 2n+1/3n)

Comment: Also, where do we get a $t$ from?

Comment: I am using the index of the sum $k$ instead of $t$ which you are using! By the way do you know how to solve the equation $cx+dy = 0$ for $x,y$?